# How to use policy iteration to solve a general environment agent in java?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, markov

I know how to solve gird world using policy iteration method. but how can I solve a general environment? My data is like this:

[image: partial data]

This is part of my data, it describe the transition model, please mention the source and destination type is String, I don't want to create a grid world.

I don't know how to define my state, and how to get them. Can I use a vector to store them? but how to define them is the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to leave the states as strings, and each unique string represents a single state.  You can store them as a dictionary of string to float.  I think in java this would be a `Map`.

```
Map<string, double> states = new HashMap<string, double>();
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick. But I need to read them from a text file, and then store them in my java file. how can I do that? Because the string is represented the "source" and "destination", and if the double type means the probability?